# JUnit mockMVC testing spring controller classes that use hibernate. Table not mapped exceptions thrown

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I'm trying to create JUnit tests for spring framework controller classes.

The class im trying to test uses hibernate/HQL to pull data from a MySQL database.

What I'm trying to test is given different parameters for the HQL, it should return specific data from the database, in this case flights.

While it does start, the test throws an exception once it tries to execute the query with

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: <tablename> is not mapped
```

Here is the JUnit class:

```
  import org.junit.Before;
  import org.junit.Test;
  import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

  import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup;


  public class SearchTest {
      private MockMvc mockMvc;

      private AjaxSearchController ajaxS;

      @Before
      public void setup() throws Exception {
          InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
          viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
          viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

          ajaxS = new AjaxSearchController();
          this.mockMvc = standaloneSetup(ajaxS).setViewResolvers(viewResolver).build();
      }

      @Test
      public void testSearch() {
          String recommendation = " ";
          String departure = "Perth, Australia";
          String arrival = "Melbourne, Australia";
          String departureDate = "2018-09-27";
          try {
              mockMvc.perform(post("/ajax")
                      .param("recommendation", recommendation)
                      .param("departure", departure)
                      .param("arrival", arrival)
                      .param("departureDate", departureDate));
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
```

The tests are being run out of the projectname.test directory.

The controller class works fine outside of JUnit, when the webapp is run normally.

How can I get hibernate to see the entity classes it needs for these tests.

Edit:

Trying to get the web application context working.
the config.xml file is located in test/resources.

```
  import org.junit.Before;
  import org.junit.Test;
  import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
  import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
  import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
  import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

  import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
  import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

  import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;


  @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
  @WebAppConfiguration
  @ContextConfiguration("classpath: config.xml")

  public class SearchTest {
      private MockMvc mockMvc;

      @Autowired
      private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

      @Before
      public void setup() throws Exception {
          this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
      }

      @Test
      public void testSearch() {
          String recommendation = " ";
          String departure = "Perth, Australia";
          String arrival = "Melbourne, Australia";
          String departureDate = "2018-09-27";
          try {
              mockMvc.perform(post("/ajax")
                      .param("recommendation", recommendation)
                      .param("departure", departure)
                      .param("arrival", arrival)
                      .param("departureDate", departureDate));
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  }
```

Gives the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [ config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

Comment: You are testing outside the scope of an application context. You are only creating a controller and do a standalone setup. There is nothing more available. You will need to bootstrap everything that is needed for this class yourself, or launch an application context to do so.

Comment: How do I launch an application context?

Comment: Have you taken the time to read (some) of the [Testing Chapter of the Spring Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework). Note this is written for JUnit 5 (previous versions of this document will show the JUnit4 way).

Comment: Yep. Still couldn't get it...

Comment: Add `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@ContextConfiguration("your config here")` and `@WebApplicationContext`. Then inject the context and use that to configure `MockMvc` that way you will have a full context available. All that is also quite nicely (imho) explained in the reference guide.

Comment: Ok, had another try. Now it cant find the config file. It should be placed in test/resources right? I've updated my post to include the changes

Comment: No it should be perfectly capable of find it from `src/main/resources`. If it is in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` it isn't on the class path and as such won't be found.

Comment: Ok, I got it to load the config. Now it can't create the beans, all throwing "Not a managed type" errors.